# Índice retornando -1 em ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Bom dia. Para fins de estudo, estou fazendo uma aplicação simples em RMI Java que simula algumas operações (criar conta, verificar saldo, debitar etc..) em um, ou mais, contas. Para cada conta criado eu gero um objeto do tipo `Conta` contendo seu respectivo número e saldo e o armazeno em um `ArrayList`. O problema ocorre quando eu preciso recuperar um objeto específico no array (utilizando o número da conta como parâmetro) para realizar alguma operação (debitar, creditar, remover e etc...). 
Estou utilizando o método `contas.indexOf(numero)` para me retornar o índice do array `contas`, mas ele sempre me retorna o índice -1.

Se eu passo algum índice, por exemplo, `Conta conta = contas.get(3)`, ele me retorna o objeto que está nessa posição. Mas preciso do índice de acordo com o número informado por parâmetro. Fiz algumas pesquisas e tentei a forma `for (Conta busca : contas)` mas também não funcionou, mesmo eu usando um `if (busca.numero == numero)`. Quando uso esse if, ele sempre dá verdadeiro, como se o número de todas as contas fosse o mesmo. E quando utilizo `if(busca.numero.equals(numero)` o netbeans apresenta um erro na declaração.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado.

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ClienteStart {

    private static ArrayList<Conta> contas = new ArrayList<Conta>();
    private static int numero;
    private static double valor;       
    private static IFuncoesBanco Funcs;
    private static Scanner scanner;

    // Aqui será simulado o "menu"
    public static void listaMetodos() {
       System.out.println("/****************************************/");
       System.out.println("/* Sistema de Contas de banco */");
       System.out.println("/* Banco da Praça */");
       System.out.println("/****************************************/\n");
       System.out.println("Escolha uma opção:");
       System.out.println("1 => Inserir nova Conta");
       System.out.println("2 => Excluir Conta");
       System.out.println("3 => Debitar da Conta");
       System.out.println("4 => Creditar da Conta");
       System.out.println("5 => Consultar Conta");
       System.out.println("6 => Sair");
       System.out.println("Digite sua opção: ");
       System.out.println("/****************************************/");
    }

    // Aqui será o método a ser executado será escolhido
    // de acordo com a opção passada pelo teclado
    public static void executeMetodo(int opcao) {
        try
        {
            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Função 'Inserir' escolhida.");
                inserir();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Função 'Excluir' escolhida.");
                excluir();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Função 'Debitar' escolhida.");
                debitar();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Função 'Creditar' escolhida.");
                creditar();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Função 'Consultar' escolhida.");
                consultar();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Encerrado");  
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Opção inválida");
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void inserir() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
        numero = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor:");
        valor = scanner.nextDouble();

        Conta contaFunc = Funcs.inserir(numero, valor);
        contas.add(contaFunc);

        System.out.println("A conta: "+contaFunc.numero+"foi criada");
    }

    private static void excluir() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
        numero = scanner.nextInt();
        valor = 0;
        int contaFunc = Funcs.excluir(contas.indexOf(numero)+1);

        contas.remove(contaFunc);

        System.out.println("A conta: "+contaFunc+"foi removida");
    }

    private static void debitar() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
        numero = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor:");
        valor = scanner.nextDouble();

        Conta contaFunc = contas.get(contas.indexOf(numero)+1);
        contaFunc = Funcs.debitar(contaFunc, valor);

        contas.add(contas.indexOf(numero)+1,contaFunc);
        System.out.println("Debitado: "+contaFunc.valor+", da conta :"+contaFunc.numero);
    }

    private static void creditar() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
        numero = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor:");
        valor = scanner.nextDouble();

        Conta contaFunc = (Conta) contas.get(contas.indexOf(numero)+1);
        contaFunc = Funcs.creditar(contaFunc, valor);

        contas.add(contas.indexOf(numero)+1,contaFunc);
        System.out.println("Creditado: "+contaFunc.valor+", da conta :"+contaFunc.numero);
    }

    private static void consultar() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
        numero = scanner.nextInt();

        for (Conta busca: contas) {

            if (busca.numero == numero) {
                System.out.println("Numero: "+busca.numero+" Saldo: "+busca.valor);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
        {
          // Localiza o serviço pelo nome
          Funcs = (IFuncoesBanco) Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.1.10:3000/Banco");

          scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
          int opcao;

          while (true) {
              listaMetodos();
              opcao = scanner.nextInt();
              executeMetodo(opcao);
         }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` retorna o índice de um objeto, no caso você tá passando um int. Você tem que iterar a lista pra achar

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Agora esta funcionando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [**`indexOf()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) recebe como parâmetro **um objeto** e retorna o index dele. Você está passando um número como parâmetro, por isso não funciona.

Para encontrar uma conta pelo seu número, será necessário percorrer toda a lista usando um `for`.

Exemplo:

```
public Conta encontraConta(int numeroConta)
{
    for(Conta c : contas)
    {
        if(c.getNumero() == numeroConta)
            return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. A aplicação da função se encaixou bem na solução do problema.

Answer (score 1):

> **indexOf(Object o)**: Retorna o índice da primeira ocorrência de um elemento específico da lista, ou -1 se a lista não contiver o elemento.

Como `int` é diferente de `Conta` nunca irá encontrar seu elemento.

Você pode alterar o `ArrayList` de conta para `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer, Conta> contas = new HashMap<>();
```

Alterar a inserção para:

```
contas.put(contaFunc.getNumero(), contaFunc);
```

E os locais que você precisa recuperar o objeto para:

```
contas.get(numero);
```

Utilizando essas alterações sua classe se parecerá com:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClienteStart {

  HashMap<Integer, Conta> contas = new HashMap<>();
  private static int numero;
  private static double valor;
  private static IFuncoesBanco Funcs;
  private static Scanner scanner;

  // Aqui será simulado o "menu"
  public static void listaMetodos() {
    System.out.println("/****************************************/");
    System.out.println("/* Sistema de Contas de banco */");
    System.out.println("/* Banco da Praça */");
    System.out.println("/****************************************/\n");
    System.out.println("Escolha uma opção:");
    System.out.println("1 => Inserir nova Conta");
    System.out.println("2 => Excluir Conta");
    System.out.println("3 => Debitar da Conta");
    System.out.println("4 => Creditar da Conta");
    System.out.println("5 => Consultar Conta");
    System.out.println("6 => Sair");
    System.out.println("Digite sua opção: ");
    System.out.println("/****************************************/");
  }

  // Aqui será o método a ser executado será escolhido
  // de acordo com a opção passada pelo teclado
  public static void executeMetodo(int opcao) {
    try {
      switch (opcao) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("Função 'Inserir' escolhida.");
          inserir();
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("Função 'Excluir' escolhida.");
          excluir();
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("Função 'Debitar' escolhida.");
          debitar();
          break;
        case 4:
          System.out.println("Função 'Creditar' escolhida.");
          creditar();
          break;
        case 5:
          System.out.println("Função 'Consultar' escolhida.");
          consultar();
          break;
        case 6:
          System.out.println("Encerrado");
          System.exit(0);
        default:
          System.out.println("Opção inválida");
          break;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void inserir() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
    numero = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor:");
    valor = scanner.nextDouble();

    Conta contaFunc = Funcs.inserir(numero, valor);
    contas.put(numero, contaFunc);

    System.out.println("A conta: " + contaFunc.numero + "foi criada");
  }

  private static void excluir() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
    numero = scanner.nextInt();
    valor = 0;
    int contaFunc = Funcs.excluir(contas.get(numero));

    contas.remove(numero);

    System.out.println("A conta: " + contaFunc + "foi removida");
  }

  private static void debitar() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
    numero = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor:");
    valor = scanner.nextDouble();

    Conta contaFunc = contas.get(numero);
    contaFunc = Funcs.debitar(contaFunc, valor);

    System.out.println("Debitado: " + contaFunc.valor + ", da conta :" + contaFunc.numero);
  }

  private static void creditar() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
    numero = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor:");
    valor = scanner.nextDouble();

    Conta contaFunc = contas.get(numero);
    contaFunc = Funcs.creditar(contaFunc, valor);

    System.out.println("Creditado: " + contaFunc.valor + ", da conta :" + contaFunc.numero);
  }

  private static void consultar() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    System.out.println("Digite o número da conta:");
    numero = scanner.nextInt();

    Conta busca = contas.get(numero)

    if (busca.numero == numero) {
      System.out.println("Numero: " + busca.numero + " Saldo: " + busca.valor);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // Localiza o serviço pelo nome
      Funcs = (IFuncoesBanco) Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.1.10:3000/Banco");

      scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
      int opcao;

      while (true) {
        listaMetodos();
        opcao = scanner.nextInt();
        executeMetodo(opcao);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação, [ArrayList#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) retorna o índice de um dado objeto. Como no seu caso é um `ArrayList` de `Conta`s, você teria que passar uma `Conta` para achar algo. Então ao invés de:

```
(Conta) contas.get(contas.indexOf(numero)+1);
```

Use apenas [ArrayList#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)), que retorna o objeto localizado em um determinado índice:

```
contas.get(numero);
```

Assim você obtém uma conta no índice indicado pelo usuário.

Obs.: Vi que no seu exemplo você sempre faz `numero+1`, você pode fazer mas não vejo utilizade para o usuário. Se eu digitar 1 eu provavelmente quero a conta número 1, não 2.

Com relação ao "[..] erro de declaração [..]" , faltou fechar um parenteses:

```
// Um parenteses para o if e outro para o método equals!
if(busca.numero.equals(numero))
```

Comment: Acho que você se confundiu, `numero` é pra ser o número da conta (valor do atributo `numero`) e não um índice.

Comment: @jbueno eu olhei os métodos creditar e debitar, nesses casos mesmo a variável se chamando numero ele usa para achar o índice(?). Está um pouco confuso para mim também

Answer (score -1):

O seu erro é, como outros já disseram, que você parece não ter entendido o `indexOf`. Ele não faz o que você quer.

Para entender como ele funciona, eis um exemplo:

```
List<String> lista = Arrays.asList("João", "Pedro", "Maria", "Lúcia");
System.out.println(lista.indexOf("Maria")); // Escreve 2.
System.out.println(lista.indexOf("João")); // Escreve 0.
System.out.println(lista.indexOf("Miguel")); // Escreve -1, não está na lista.
```

Observe que isso significa que o `indexOf` não vai te servir, pois ele localiza a posição em que um objeto está a partir do objeto a ser procurado. Isso não é o que você quer, pois o que você precisa é localizar um objeto de acordo com uma chave.

Uma forma de fazer isso seria iterar todas as posições da lista, tal como você faz no seu método `consultar()`. Mas se você está precisando fazer esse tipo de coisa, é sinal de que está tomando uma abordagem errada, pois imagine como seria em um sistema real com milhões de registros se isso fosse necessário, claramente essa não é a melhor abordagem.

O que você precisa é localizar contas com base em seu número. Ou seja, precisa de alguma coisa que faça um **mapeamento** do número da conta para os dados da própria conta. Ou seja, precisa de um `Map`.

Assim sendo, ao invés de uma lista, declare o seu conjunto de contas assim:

```
private static final Map<Integer, Conta> contas = new HashMap<>();
```

No seu método de `inserir()`, ao invés disso:

```
    Conta contaFunc = Funcs.inserir(numero, valor);
    contas.add(contaFunc);

    System.out.println("A conta: "+contaFunc.numero+"foi criada");
```

Faça isso:

```
    if (contas.containsKey(numero)) {
        System.out.println("Essa conta já existe.");
    } else {
        Conta contaFunc = Funcs.inserir(numero, valor);
        contas.put(numero, contaFunc);
        System.out.println("A conta: " + numero + " foi criada.");
    }
```

No método `debitar()`, ao invés disso:

```
    Conta contaFunc = contas.get(contas.indexOf(numero)+1);
    contaFunc = Funcs.debitar(contaFunc, valor);

    contas.add(contas.indexOf(numero)+1,contaFunc);
    System.out.println("Debitado: "+contaFunc.valor+", da conta :"+contaFunc.numero);
```

Faça isso:

```
    Conta contaFunc = contas.get(numero);
    if (contaFunc == null) {
        System.out.println("Essa conta não existe.");
    } else {
        contaFunc = Funcs.debitar(contaFunc, valor);
        System.out.println("Debitado " + valor + " da conta " + numero + ". O novo saldo é de " + contaFunc.valor + ".");
    }
```

O seu método `creditar()` é parecido com o `debitar()`. Note que você estava confundindo `valor`, que é o valor debitado, com `contaFunc.valor`, que é o saldo da conta.

No seu método `excluir()`, ao invés disso:

```
    int contaFunc = Funcs.excluir(contas.indexOf(numero)+1);

    contas.remove(contaFunc);

    System.out.println("A conta: "+contaFunc+"foi removida");
```

Faça isso:

```
    Conta contaFunc = contas.get(numero);
    if (contaFunc == null) {
        System.out.println("Essa conta já não existia.");
    } else {
        contas.remove(numero);
        Funcs.excluir(contaFunc);
        System.out.println("A conta: " + numero + " foi removida.");
    }
```

E por fim, o seu método `consultar()` não precisa percorrer a lista. Ao invés disso:

```
    for (Conta busca: contas) {

        if (busca.numero == numero) {
            System.out.println("Numero: "+busca.numero+" Saldo: "+busca.valor);
        }
    }
```

Use isso:

```
    Conta conta = contas.get(numero);
    if (conta == null) {
        System.out.println("Essa conta não existe.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("A conta " + numero + " tem saldo de " + busca.valor + ".");
    }
```

Comment: Alguém pode explicar o motivo do -1? O que há de errado aqui?